# How to call Html.Raw and Html.Partial outside a razor page?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have this requirements. I need to be able to write this code in my razor views:

```
@Filters.Render(Filters.DateRangeFilter, new DateRangeFilterParameters { });
```

The alternative is:

```
@Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/DateRangeFilter.cshtml", new DateRangeFilterParameters { });
```

In other words, I want `Filters` class to wrap `Html.Partial`. For that reason, I thought of this code:

```
public class Filters {
    public const string DateRangeFilter = "/Views/Shared/DateRangeFilter.cshtml";

    public static HtmlString Render(string filterPath, object parameters)
    {
        // Here I need to call Html.Partail, how?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use Html.Raw within the controller you can request the injected `IHtmlHelper` service. E.g.:

```
HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IHtmlHelper)) as IHtmlHelper;
```

Or you can do your own implementation for the helper. And in order to use `Html.Partial` you need to use `IRazorViewEngine`, `ViewContext`, and other stuff. So basically you need to implement a service for that, and here is a good example [Render Partial View To String Outside Controller Context](https://www.surinderbhomra.com/Blog/Post/2018/09/02/ASPNET-Core-Render-Partial-View-To-String-Outside-Controller-Context).

I don't know if there is an easier way to achieve those, but that is what on my mind.